# How can I make search form that searches to Yahoo Finance Ticker Lookup?

Tags: html

Okay so i just wanted to put a little search form on my site that when submitted it submits the text to the search form on Yahoo Ticker Symbol Lookup.

I tried doing the

```
form action="http://www.domain.com/search" method="GET" target="_blank"
```

method but it doesnt work
My exact code is:

```
    <form action="http://finance.yahoo.com/q" method="POST">
    <input type="text">
    </form>
```

please help.

Comment: http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=MSFT works just fine for me. What field name do you use?

Comment: In order to make the task easier, please add the whole `<form>` tag along with the `input` fields and a `submit` button so that everyone willing to help would be able to do so without spending his or her time building the form again. Thank you.

Comment: it says To get a quote, enter a company name or stock symbol in the quote box above.

Comment: see my answer: I believe you did not choose the input name correctly.

Comment: okay so it works but its submitting the value of the button now.

Comment: it does not hurt, does it? Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works just fine for me. The essential part that you are missing is `name="s"`:

```
<form action="http://finance.yahoo.com/q" method="GET" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
</form>
```